# Cant we use this selection sort algorithm for better time complexity?

Tags: python-3.x, selection-sort

i am new in this programming word. I was reading about the selection sort algorithm. I saw the examples. I saw the python example in GeeksforGeeks( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/ ) website. I thought that i can write more efficient code which time complexity is less than O(n^2).

```
arr = [64, 25, 12, 22, 11]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    smallest_number = min(arr[i:])
    smallest_number_index = arr.index(smallest_number, i)
    arr[i] , arr[smallest_number_index] = arr[smallest_number_index], arr[i]
print(arr)
```

in this code the time complexity is O(1).
so can i use this code instead of geeksforgeeks code???

Comment: Complexity of your algorithm is even worse, O(n^3) to be precise (if I'm not wrong). You have 3 nested loops: The outer one and two more hidden by function calls ( `min()` and `arr.index()`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood complexity calculation as well as you assumed that standard methods calls ( min and index) are O(1) operations. They are not, they are O(n) operations.

Let me write complexity of each line of your code in front of line.

```
for i in range(len(arr)): ->  O(n)
    smallest_number = min(arr[i:]) -> O(n)
    smallest_number_index = arr.index(smallest_number, i) -> O(n)
    arr[i] , arr[smallest_number_index] = arr[smallest_number_index], arr[i] -> O(1)
```

To calculate complexity of one loop iteration sum complexities of all lines under loop : O(n) + O(n) + O(1) = 2*O(n) +1 which is equivalent to O(n)
and now as you are running loop n times, you have to multiply it by complexity of one loop iteration i.e O(n)
so total complexity : n * O(n) = O(n^2)

Comment: which one is best ??? mine or geeksforgeeks code sample????

Comment: Yes, you can call your code a selection sort algorithm, algorithm is exactly same only implementation detail is changing. Although time complexities are O(n^2) for both the codes, geeksforgeeks one is more efficient than your approach as that is calculating smallest number index in "n" iterations while your code is taking 2*n iterations for the same.